# class NumberpickercustomlayoutBinding is public, should be declared in a file named NumberpickercustomlayoutBinding.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-databinding

I have enabled data binding in my android studio project. Whenever I build my project it shows this error:

" error: class NumberpickercustomlayoutBinding is public, should be declared in a file named NumberpickercustomlayoutBinding.java
public final class NumberpickercustomlayoutBinding implements ViewBinding { "

It also gives me the path for the file but whenever I edit it according to the class name, it is regenerated again with the old name of the class and error is bing shown again
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/komv9.png).

I tried renaming it by following the link to the build folder, but on building the project it agains make the class name to initial name and the error still resides there.

Comment: seems to me this is a file from an import, you'll have to update it in the original library/project it's in. Either way, the error is pretty clear

Comment: clean project and rebuild again it should solve your problem.

Comment: @Laser of course that won't resolve the problem. the problem is in a library on which the project has a dependency.

Comment: remove the import clean rebuild and then again import. I always face this issue but doing this always solves mine. @SHAURYA MALHOTRA Moreover do share the image where you have used ```numberpickerCustomLayoutBinding``` the image u shared is a build file which is not meant to be changed.

Comment: @Laser which is why your solution won't work. He needs to modify the code in the dependent library, otherwise a re-build will re-build it faulty, yet again.

Comment: @Stultuske you are right , it re-builds and error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the changes to file in the original library it is present in. As you can see in your image, it mentions "Files under the build "folder" are generated and should not be edited".
During every build, an equivalent class of your original java file is generated.

- Search for the class you have to edit. You will find it in two places
  after the build. One under "build" folder and one under the original
  library/project you have created.
- Edit it in the original library  and you will be able to see the
  changes after the build in the "build" folder.

Comment: There was some issue in one of my Xml file.
I removed it and it is working now. 

According to your solution , i was only able to find it in build folder. 
I gave a hard look into it but wasn't able to find it in original library/project.